# Dynamically add dropdown after increasing type number

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add and remove a dropdown list based on the number selected in an input field with type number.

Upon incrementing the number I want to add another clone of a previously created dropdown list. After decrementing i want the last one to be removed again. Keeping the other ones with their respective values.

My code so far keeps adding dropdowns but it's not good coding how it's done. I don't know how to get the last element removed dynamically.

Html:

```
<div class="row step2">
    <h3>Aantal deelorganisaties inclusief hoofdorganisatie</h3>
    <p>Kies het aantal deelorganisaties voor wie je het samengestelde lidmaatschap ook wil activeren</p>
    <div>
        <input type="number" name="suborgamount" class="suborgamount" min="0" value="0"/> 
        <i class="fa fa-times suborgpriceperyear">
    </div>
    <div class="headorgdropdownholder col-md-12">
        <p class="col-md-5">Selecteer je eigen organisatie voor het lidmaatschap te activeren:</p>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 space filter-fields" style="padding-right: 0">
            <select class="selectpicker" id="orgdropdown" data-live-search="true">
                <?php 
                    foreach ($allorgs as $org) {
                        echo "<option data-tokens=\"$org->name\">orgid: $org->org_id - naam: $org->name</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="suborgdropdownholder col-md-12">

    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".suborgamount").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    addRemoveDropdownList();
});


function addRemoveDropdownList() {
    var container = $("<p class='col-md-4'>Selecteer deelorganisatie(s) waarvoor het lidmaatschap ook geactiveerd moet worden:</p>");
    $('.suborgdropdownholder').html(container);

    // Finding total number of elements added
    var total_element = $('input[name=suborgamount]').val();

    // last <div> with element class id
    var lastid = $(".selectpicker:last").attr("id");
    var split_id = lastid.split("_");
    var nextindex = Number(split_id[1]) + 1;
    if (isNaN(nextindex)) {
        nextindex = 1;
    }

    var newselect = $('#orgdropdown').clone().attr({
        style:'display: block !important',
        id:'suborgdropdown_'+nextindex
    });

    $(".selectpicker:last").after(newselect);
}
```

JSFiddle showing the problem [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uf3ctsqe/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this JS code adds dropdowns every time the input number changes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var prevCount = 0;

  $(".suborgamount").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {
    var total_element = $('input[name=suborgamount]').val();
    if (prevCount != total_element){
        addRemoveDropdownList();    
    }
  });


  function addRemoveDropdownList() {
    var total_element = $('input[name=suborgamount]').val();
    prevCount = total_element;
    var selectPickers = $(".suborgdropdownholder > select");
    var container = $("<p class='col-md-4'>Selecteer deelorganisatie(s) waarvoor het lidmaatschap ook geactiveerd moet worden:</p>");
    $('.suborgdropdownholder').html(container);
    $(".selectpicker").not(':first').remove();
    var nextIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < total_element; i++){
      var newselect = $('#orgdropdown').clone().attr({
        style:'display: block !important',
        id:'suborgdropdown_'+nextIndex
      });
      if (selectPickers[nextIndex]){
          newselect.find('option[value='+ $(selectPickers[nextIndex]).val() +']').prop('selected', true);
      }
      $('.suborgdropdownholder').append(newselect);
      nextIndex++;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great! Is there also a way, when the amount changes (becomes less or more), that all the dropdowns which are not removed keep the value they had? Right now they all revert back to the default value.

Comment: I updated the code. The values do not revert back to the default value on mouse up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! unfortunately, it does not seem to be working, using your code, the functionality remains the same and all the dropdowns do get reset

Comment: I guess you don’t want the values to reset when the input number is changed to blank?

Comment: When entering for example 4 in the input number, I then make sure all the dropdowns have a selected value. I then change the number to 5 in the input field. And all 5 dropdowns are reset to the default value (instead of keeping the values I put them on)

Comment: Updated the code. The values are now preserved when the number changes (unless you set the number to blank).

Answer (score 1):

I can see multiple reasons why your code is not working as intented:

- You should use `change` events instead of `keyup mouseup` events, so that focusing the input will not increase the number of dropdowns
- The input is not reflecting the number of dropdowns. When the user inputs 8 after the initial load (input was 0), you will end up with 2 dropdowns. You may want to reconsider this behaviour, as it will be probably confusing for the user.

For the rest of my answer, I will assume you want to have the same number of dropdowns as displayed in the input. To achieve this, you can:

- initialize the input with 1 instead of 0
- when the input value changes (`change`event):

  - retrieve the number of dropdown you want at the end (from the input)
  - count the number of dropdown you have: `$('.selectpicker').length`
  - if the total number is below the desired number, iterate over an index starting from existing number to desired number, clone the last dropdown `$('selectpicker:last')`, use the index for the id of the clone, and append the clone to the container
  - if the total number is above the desired number, iterate over an index starting from the existing number to the desired number and remove the last dropdown form the container.